# Loop handling in java

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

Hey there I have a problem in java while printing... I have program in which I need to print some values which are in a loop. In every repetition of loop there is a new value formed now i want there should be when the loop end first value of first repetition should print then second and then so on... but in my case it is only printing the values of last execution[image]

Here i upload the picture of my output u can clearly see that only the values of last loop are printed
but i want in first row there should be the values of first loop in second row there should be the values of second loop and in third row there should be the values of third loop.

Here is my code

```
public class ManufactureClass {

        private static void outputtable() {


                    System.out.println(
                            "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("| No. of Order | No. of Units | Time Consumed by WA | Time Consumed by WB | Time Consumed by WH | Effective Units | Defective Units | Total Time Consumed By this Order | No. of Packages |");
                    System.out.println(
                            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    for(int i=1;i<=total_orders;i++) {
                    long sum=Long.sum((time_consumed_by_Work_Station_H_in_thread_sleep_for_units_greater_than_30/1000), (time_consumed_by_Work_Station_B_in_thread_sleep/1000));
                    long sum1=Long.sum((time_consumed_by_Work_Station_A_in_integer/1000), sum);
                    total_time_consumed_by_order=Long.toString(sum1)+" seconds";
                    if(units_in_an_order<=30) {
                        System.out.println("|       "+loop_for_orders+"       |      "+number_of_units_in_order+"      | "+actual_time_by_Work_Station_A_in_seconds+" | "+actual_time_by_Work_Station_B_in_seconds+" | "+actual_time_by_Work_Station_H_in_seconds_for_units_less_than_30+" | "+effective_units+" | "+defective_units+" | "+total_time_consumed_by_order+" | "+number_of_packages_for_units_less_than_30+" | ");
                        System.out.println(
                                "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        }else {

                        System.out.println("|      "+loop_for_orders+"       |      "+number_of_units_in_order+"      | "+actual_time_by_Work_Station_A_in_seconds+" | "+actual_time_by_Work_Station_B_in_seconds+" | "+actual_time_by_Work_Station_H_in_seconds_for_units_greater_than_30+" | "+effective_units+" | "+defective_units+" | "+total_time_consumed_by_order+" | "+number_of_packages_for_units_greater_than_30+" | ");
                        System.out.println(
                                "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        }
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            display_header();
            display_msg();

            for(loop_for_orders=1;loop_for_orders<=total_orders;loop_for_orders++) {
                Random rand = new Random(); 
                units_in_an_order = rand.nextInt(200);
                number_of_units_in_order=Integer.toString(units_in_an_order);
                int a=10;
                int b=100;
                defective_units =(float) (0.01*units_in_an_order);
                effective_units=units_in_an_order-defective_units;
            int zero1=0;
            int zero2=0;
            time_consumed_by_Work_Station_A = "" + units_in_an_order + zero1+zero2;
            time_consumed_by_Work_Station_A_in_integer = Long.parseLong(time_consumed_by_Work_Station_A);
            interval = units_in_an_order;
        Manufactured_units_by_work_station_A();
        permission();




        }
}


    outputtable();
}
```

Comment: Please, reduce your issue to something much, much shorter than that. Also, indent your code properly, and strictly respect the Java naming conventions. My guess is that you don't really understand what `static` means. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: can u help me regarding my loop problem.. i have reduced the code

Comment: Puh, huge pile of code, everything in one class and static, try to utilize OOP correctly. Your problem: You are overwriting the values you are printing in every step of the loop and then printing the result of the last iteration. You need to store the values you want to print in a list instead of overwriting them each time. However, this is only a dirty fix. I suggest you to refactor the whole code.

Comment: Apparently, you haven't read my comment: your code is still huge, it still doesn't respect the Java naming conventions, it still has plenty of static variables, and I doubt you have read the page I linked to in these few seconds.

Comment: @Philipp i have reduced the code i know how program is executing . I also know that loop is printing only last value of iteration because i am printing at end of loop ..is there any method that end of loop i can print every value of loop

Comment: have a look now i have reduced the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well on the second sight and as was mentioned above in the comments, you owerwrite your values in each iteration. You may need wether an ArrayList or a collection to store the values you receive in every iteration.

DO something like this.

```
    public class ManufactureClass {

      static ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

     function  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      //(...)

        for(loop_for_orders=1;loop_for_orders<=total_orders;loop_for_orders++) {
              myArrayList.add(yourOutputString);
         }
    }
```

In your Output-Funktion you just have to go through the ArrayList and maybe even set this function in a static context - but a structure like that is definitley the way to go.

Edit: Well it's a bit more complicated if you want to generate an output in lines, but remeber - key is the right DataStructure and an appropriate way to handle it, that works for you. :)

Edit 2: So in case we go through the array List in a second function in the same class it looks like this:

```
    public void printMyOutputLine(){
            for(j=0;j<this.myArrayList.size();j++)
            {
               System.out.println(this.myArrayList[j]);
             }

     }
```

It's really basic - the only problem is the "trick" to get all of your Data in the List by using an apropriate DataStructure for - in this case an ArrayList I guessed, but might be you'd rather work with a collection or a StringArray. You'll figure it out - the dexcriped way shall lead you in the right direction.

Comment: ok after adding the values in array list how will i print those at the end of loop

Comment: I'd write a function for it :)

Comment: ok dude i m waiting ...lets take in output string if there is value 1 then 2 how will i print that

Comment: Something like: printThisOutputLine: (for-loop i) System.out.prinln(ManufactureClassOBject.myArrayList[j]); hard to explain that in the comments because of a lack of possibilites to write code in here.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the described Problem should not be that tough :) Was hard to read this from your first Snipplet (now it's better) - to me the described problem rather indicates, that the intended value is not handled correctly and you just get the Loop's last iteration.

If your code looks like the snipplet you gave, I'd bet it might be a problem with your indent style - that may cause a problem for the compiler.

```
    Example - would work fine:
    startprog
      for 10 do left 20
            if firstvariable do up 30
            endif
            if secondvariable do right 40 + 30
            endif
      endfor
    endprog
```

We see a well indented prgramming style, that is clearly working above.
Beneath the oppposite - a weird Construct of cases that will automatically break the loop.

```
    Example - might be the problem:

    for 10 do left 20
            if firstvariable do up 30
            endif
   myLoopBreakingFunction(); //will leave the loop becaue of wrong indent_count             
            if secondvariable do right 40 + 30
            endif
      endfor
    endprog
```

Just try to bring the commands  `Manufactured_units_by_work_station_A();` and `permission();` in line and see if this does the trick.

Comment: i didn't understand... can u elaborate a bit more

Comment: Can u help on teamviewer?

Comment: I wrote a second answer :) hope both help. I just say here: be carefull with spaces from the right corner and get the FunctionCalls in Line with the for-Loop.